# size of `struct sockaddr`

Tags: sockets, ipv6, unix-socket

I know that `struct sockaddr` is supposed to be a generic socket type.
But `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` returns `16` and `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)` returns `28`.
In this case, how does `struct sockaddr` achieve its goal of being a generic type, when it itself is smaller than `struct sockaddr_in6`

Specifically, I'm trying to use the `connect()` function to create a ipv6 socket. Since `connect()` accepts only a `sockaddr*` argument, how do I tell the ipv6 address to it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `sizeof struct sockaddr_in6`.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols.

Comment: In that case, @Ron Maupin, how do I create a IPv6 socket?

Answer (score 0):

The first member of both `socketaddr_in` and `socketaddr_in6`
is of type: `typedef unsigned short int sa_family_t`.
It's value is either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.
By this `connect()` knows it can cast `socketaddr_in` to `socketaddr_in6`.

```cpp
struct in6_addr address;
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &address);
uint16_t port = 8080;
if (domain == PF_INET6) {
    ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr)->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr)->sin6_addr = &address;
    ((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr)->sin6_port = htons(port);
    addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
}
else {
    ((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr)->sin_family = AF_INET;
    ((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr)->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)&address.__in6_u.__u6_addr32[3];
    ((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr)->sin_port = htons(port);
    addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
}
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrLen);
```